# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest | API Call

Tags: json, api, powershell, httpwebrequest

I'm using Gitea and I try to create a user using an API call in PowerShell:

> Testing Plateforme : https://try.gitea.io/
>
> API URL : https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger
>
> API Token : 3bb81a498393f4af3d278164b5755fc23b74b785
>
> Username : Will-stackoverflow
>
> Password : willwill

Here it's what I have tried so far :

```
# Filling my var with some data
$username="myuser"
$email="myuser@mydomain.com"
$full_name="My User"
$password="P@$$w0rd"

# Building a hash with my data
$hash = @{
     Email = $($email);
     full_name = $($full_name);
     login_name = $($username);
     Password = $($password);
     send_notify = "false";
     source_id = 0;
     Username = $($username)
}

# Converting my hash to json format
$JSON = $hash | convertto-json
# Displaying my JSON var
$JSON

Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://try.gitea.io/api/v1/admin/users?access_token=3bb81a498393f4af3d278164b5755fc23b74b785" -Method POST -Body $JSON
```

My `$JSON` var is fed properly :

```
{
    "Password":  "P@w0rd",
    "full_name":  "My User",
    "Username":  "myuser",
    "Email":  "myuser@mydomain.com",
    "source_id":  0,
    "login_name":  "myuser",
    "send_notify":  "false"
}
```

But there is the result (from my prod environement as I can't get it to work at all using the online plateforme) :

[image]

To me it sounds like the fields `"Username"`, `"Email"` and `"Password"` are required, but they are filled in my displayed JSON. What am I missing or doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

Adding the `-ContentType 'application/json'` parameter to the `Invoke-WebRequest` command as suggested by Theo :

[image]

Comment: I notice the fields' order isn't the same after converting to json. Could that be the issue? If yeah how to keep the right field at the right place ?

Comment: the order of the fields should not matter. A hashtable has no specific order

Comment: Have you tried adding the auth token to the header? `Invoke-WebRequest -H 'Authorization: token AUTH_TOKEN_HERE`?

Comment: If i read the error message correctly, it complains about the value in your JSON for "send_notify". Try changing `"send_notify":  "false"` into `"send_notify":  $false`. That way it receives a Boolean value instead of the string `"false"`. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Swagger UI](https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger#/admin/adminCreateUser) site, it seems to me the json must contain properties in lower-caps only

```
{
  "email": "myuser@mydomain.com",
  "full_name": "My User",
  "login_name": "myuser",
  "password": "P@w0rd",
  "send_notify": $true,
  "source_id": 0,
  "username": "myuser"
}
```

Also, according to the Swagger site, you need to state the **-ContentType**.
Your code would look like this:

```
# Filling my var with some data
$username="myuser"
$email="myuser@mydomain.com"
$full_name="My User"
$password="P@$$w0rd"

# Building a hash with my data
$hash = @{
     email = $($email);          # string
     full_name = $($full_name);  # string
     login_name = $($username);  # string
     password = $($password);    # string
     send_notify = $false;       # boolean
     source_id = 0;              # int
     username = $($username)     # string
}



# Converting my hash to json format
$JSON = $hash | ConvertTo-Json
# Displaying my JSON var
$JSON

# just to make it somewhat easier on the eyes
$token = "3bb81a498393f4af3d278164b5755fc23b74b785"
$url = "http://try.gitea.io/api/v1/admin/users?access_token=$token"

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: This is what I did in the first place but because the error message outputed by PowerShell was showing those fieldNames with caps, I've added them afterward. No luck :/

Comment: I also think you should add `-ContentType 'application/json'` to your `Invoke-WebRequest` command.

Comment: I have updated my post with the new message I'm getting. I don't know if we've been forward or backward adding that line x)

Comment: ..but you didn't add `-ContentType 'application/json'` to the command.

Comment: I did Theo, that's why the message changed : `Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/admin/users?access_token=xxx" Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $JSON`